# Kotlin best way to implement lazy var with ability to update

Tags: kotlin, delegates, lazy-initialization

What is the best way to implement a variable with a lazy initialization, a private setter and an ability to change value with an expensive method?

I mean something like this:

```
private const val NO_INIT = "noInit"

class LazyUpdatableVarClass {
    private val initValue by lazy { expensive() }
    var value = NO_INIT
        private set
        get() {
            if (field == NO_INIT) {
                field = initValue
            }
            return field
        }

    fun updateValue() {
        value += expensive()
    }

    private fun expensive() = "hello"
}
```

Is this the shortest and best way to do it? Custom delegate, I think, isn't short because I need an implementation for it. Or maybe is there a library delegate for that?

Example of usage:

```
val example = LazyUpdatableVarClass()
assertEquals("hello", example.value)
example.updateValue()
assertEquals("hellohello", example.value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you aren’t making it thread-safe since your example code isn’t, it would be more concise and less overhead to use a nullable backing property and omit the redundant Lazy delegate.

```
class LazyUpdatableVarClass {
    private var _value: String? = null
    var value: String
        private set(x) { _value = x }
        get() = _value ?: expensive().also { _value = it }

    fun updateValue() {
        value += expensive()
    }

    private fun expensive() = "hello"
}
```

You might consider also making it a `val` and modifying it exclusively through the backing property but that would require changes in your other methods of this class:

```
class LazyUpdatableVarClass {
    private var _value: String? = null
    val value: String
        get() = _value ?: expensive().also { _value = it }

    fun updateValue() {
        _value = value + expensive()
    }

    private fun expensive() = "hello"
}
```

Comment: I like the second option, it has only 3 lines!

Answer (score 2):

Custom delegate for mutable `value` won't help you, because you cannot have private setter (or any custom setter/getter) with delegate.

The cleaner way to implement this API is to declare `value` as `val` and use mutable [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties) (`_value`):

```kotlin
class LazyUpdatableVarClass {
    private lateinit var _value: String
    private fun getValueOrInit(): String {
        if (!::_value.isInitialized) _value = expensive()
        return _value
    }

    fun updateValue() {
        _value = getValueOrInit() + expensive()
    }

    val value get() = getValueOrInit()

    private fun expensive() = "hello"
}
```